# Docker run "someImage" returns: standard_init_linux.go190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: arm, dht22, docker, golang

As the title said, I cannot reproduce this kind of error in any Dockerfiles of mine, after trying to run the Docker Container with

```
docker run registryName:tag
```

I'm trying to cross compile from `amd64` -> `arm6` via `gitLab CI`

**1. Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:1.10.2-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/.../.../dht22
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache alpine-sdk  \
    && go get ./... \
    && GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -a -o app .

FROM arm32v6/alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder /go/src/.../.../dht22/app /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

**2. `Dockerfile.arm6` to Cross Compile and run Golang binary on Raspberry Pi:**

```
FROM golang:1.10.2 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/.../.../dht22
COPY . .
RUN go tool dist list | grep arm \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi \
    && go get ./... \
    && CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -a -o app .

FROM arm32v6/alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder /go/src/.../.../dht22/app /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

**What I have tried so far**

- Adding `!#bin/bash || !#bin/sh`
- Reinstall Docker
- `CGO_ENABLED=0` isn`t an option cause my Golang dht22 Project has  C dependencies

Dockerinfo from Raspberry where my container should run:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   ....
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:30:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   ....
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:30:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
 Experimental: false
```

- Why do I have this error message?

Edit:

- A simple Hello World does work in a container with those configs (with 0 dependencies, only "fmt" as package).
- My golang project has a third library dependency (https://github.com/d2r2/go-dht) I suspect this throws the error causes of missing dependencies during the build.
- Instead of Cross Compiling , Ive build my Image with the 1st Dockerfile 
  on my `Raspberry pi (arm).`Container runs about 3h and then exites with 
  `Code: 139`

Answer (score 1):

My Problem is fixed. Reason was GCC Compiler plus Alpine in addition.
I turned my back to alpine and switched to

```
resin/arm7hf-debian
```

as Base Image. Alpine missed a lib3 directory (Probably a System Library) which was the reason why Docker exits with a `error Code 190 no such file or directory`

Here is my new `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.10.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/git/name/dht22
COPY . .
RUN go tool dist list | grep arm \
   && apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y build-essential gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi \
   && go get ./... \
   && CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm 
      GOARM=6 go build -a -o dht22binary dht22.go

FROM resin/armv7hf-debian
WORKDIR /go/src/git/name/dht22
COPY --from=builder /go/src/git/name/dht22 /dht22binary
ENTRYPOINT ['./dht22binary']
```

For all those who are trying to building on a alpine with `CGO_ENABLED=1`. Just use `Debian` instead of `Alpine` as base Image

Edit note:

- For Raspberry PI 3 user take `FROM resin/raspberrypi3-debian` as Base
  Image
- To run Your Container with those Docker configs use following Command:

  `docker run --privileged -d yourimage`

**Important:** `--privileged -d` (in a nutshell) grants your Docker Container GPIO Access

`Image Size:`
22.56 MiB

Answer (score 0):

Your cross-compilation seems erroneous. You should replace `alpine:latest` to `arm32v6/alpine:latest` in your `Dockerfile.arm6` file and recompile your image

Comment: I have fixed my `Dockerfile.arm6` to `arm32v6/alpine:latest` but it still throws this error: `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`